# History of other commits are listed in push

Tags: git, push, rebase

I'm using bitucket and created a branch to the master. I have made some edits and then want to do a pull request. For that I did a rebase onto the master (which had a few changed by other people). When I do a rebase onto the master and then commit and push my branch, the history of the commits that have happened by other into the master (via pull requests) are included in the changelog of my push. Is this expected behaviour?

Here the chronological order again (I was using a GUi, so can't give
   you the exact commands):

- checkout branch
- make edits
- rebase onto master
- commit and push

Comment: When you rebase, all treated commits will be considered as new since their hashes (uid) have changed. `I did a rebase` not to specific, if you rebased the commits you're talking about then the answer is yes

Comment: Yes I did a rebase of my commits onto the master. Is this the correct procedure?

Comment: Rebasing a shared branch is very dangerous, we should avoid it. You should've created your own branch and once finished you should've merged it into master

Comment: my branch is not shared, it is my own. In order to merge it to the master I need to create a pull request. For that I need to rebase it first, don't I?

Comment: Please update your post with the commands you performed.